# PhoneGap: Getting uncaught exception when setting ContactAddress

Tags: cordova

I'm using PhoneGap to save contacts on iPhone/Android.  Overall it does seem to be working, but I've traced a recent crash to the fact that it throws an uncaught exception when I try to set a physical address into a contactAddress() object within my contact() object.

I did JSON.stringify on the contact I am trying to save:

```
{
    "id": 41,
    "rawId": null,
    "displayName": "Joe Customer",
    "name": {
        "givenName": "Joe",
        "familyName": "Customer"
    },
    "nickname": null,
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "name": "work",
            "value": "2145556666",
            "pref": true
        },
        {
            "name": "fax",
            "value": "2147778888",
            "pref": true
        }
    ],
    "addresses": [
        {
            "streetAddress": null,
            "locality": "Dallas",
            "region": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "country": null
        }
    ],
    "ims": null,
    "organizations": [
        {
            "pref": true,
            "type": "work",
            "name": "Acme Inc.",
            "department": null,
            "title": "Sales Person"
        }
    ],
    "birthday": null,
    "note": null,
    "photos": null,
    "categories": null,
    "urls": [
        {
            "name": "website",
            "value": "http://www.google.com",
            "pref": true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to save this, I get the exception:

```
2012-09-06 21:50:38.358 MyApp[6224:707] typeValue: (null)

2012-09-06 21:50:38.359 MyApp[6224:707] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: type)
```

It seems to happen regardless of whether I fill out the entire address object or just one field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set the 'rawId' field of the contact. I did also have a problem saving contacts on Android devices when working with Phonegap 2.1 and Sencha Touch 2.0 and I got a similar log output, something with "invalid argument: int is 'null'" or something. The problem was solved when I realized that I had to set the rawId of the contact.

In my case, I just wanted to update an already existing contact so I set the id of my contact object, contactToSave, to the same id as the contact I wanted to update. But when contactToSave.save() executed, there was the beforementioned error.

When I set not only the id but also the rawId of contactToSave to the same as the contact in the phonebook, the problem disappeared and I could update contacts without problem.

Try setting the rawId of your contact, though I don't know to what value, since it is a new contact.